# Django: Structure to import file

Tags: django, structure

I have a general question about project structure in Django. I have several apps on my website. Let's say App A & App B

I have now an API code which I want to import in both apps. I couldn't find a page answering me this question so I want to ask you here. Where in the project folder should I store this SOMEAPI.py file to import it in both app?

Comment: Anywhere it makes the most sense. You can import the file anywhere you want to use it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't overthink it, it's not that important and it can be changed easily. If the file is mostly related to `A`, I'll put in `A` and use `import some_api from A` wherever you need it. Same thing if it's mostly related to `B`. If it's really independent from both apps, what I often do is create another app `common` which contains all the code common to the other apps (usually some function helpers), like `common.some_api`, `common.helpers` etc...

Comment: Okay great, thank you. I will use App A then.  Do you usually create a folder where you save such APIs or other code you import in e.g. views.py or do you just save it in the main app folder? I know I quite overthinking here, but I just want to learn it the right.

Comment: Personally I literally create a folder named `common` where I put all code not really related to any app but that it is used all over the project. For instance you should not have any import from an other app, like `A` or `B` in this folder, since in that case the code should likely be put in the given app.

Comment: Ok great. As my app B had a bit more references to this code I saved the file now in a folder auth and also import this folder to app A. Thanks a lot for your input!